# ValueError: X has 2 features, but SVC is expecting 472082 features as input

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm

I am loading Linear SVM model and then predicting new data using the stored trained SVM Model. I used TFIDF while training such as:

```
vector = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 3)).fit(data['text'])
```

**when i apply new data than I am getting error at the time of Prediction.
**

ValueError: X has 2 features, but SVC is expecting 472082 features as input.

**Code for the Prediction of new data**

```
Linear_SVC_classifier = joblib.load("/content/drive/MyDrive/dataset/Classifers/Linear_SVC_classifier.sav")
test_data = input("Enter Data for Testing: ")
newly_testing_data = vector.transform(test_data)
SVM_Prediction_NewData = Linear_SVC_classifier.predict(newly_testing_data)
```

I want to predict new data using stored SVM model without applying TFIDF on training data when I give data to model for prediction. When I use the new data for prediction than the prediction line gives error. Is there any way to remove this error?

Comment: Is your prediction vectorizer the same one that was used during training?

Comment: yes i used TFIDF Both times

Comment: vector = TfidfVectorizer().fit(test_data) I used this line for predicting new data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is due to your creation of a new `TfidfVectorizer` by fitting it on the test dataset. As the classifier has been trained on a matrix generated by the `TfidfVectorier` fitted on the training dataset, it expects the test dataset to have the exact same dimensions.
In order to do so, you need to transform your test dataset with the ***same vectorizer that was used during training*** rather than initialize a new one based on the test set.

The vectorizer fitted on the train set can be pickled and stored for later use to avoid any re-fitting at inference time.

Comment: Yes, you are right. but I am trying to not apply every time tfidf on train-test dataset for fitting new string(data) into SVM

Comment: is there any way to do this?

Comment: You don't have to fit the vectorizer on your train dataset every-time. Do it once during the training phase, store the fitted vectorizer with the use of pickle/joblib, and load it again in order to transform the input data.

Comment: Post this Answer i wil accept it.

Comment: I'd rather add that to the original answer for full context